# MySQL Trigger to RabbitMQ Communication

Tags: mysql, .net, rabbitmq

I have an application on Sql Server that send change data to Target database using Sql Service Broker. I just capture the data from Trigger and push data into service broker Queue. Now I want to make compatible my application to MySql. Now the problem is how i achive exactly the same implementation in MySql because its not supported. If I use external Message Broker like RabbitMq how MySql Table Trigger directly communicate with RabbitMq.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

If you can use Kafka as an alternative to RabbitMQ there are some tutorials on how to accomplish a similar goal:

1. [Using Kafka Connect](https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/en/message-queue-for-apache-kafka/latest/use-kafka-connect-to-synchronize-data-from-a-mysql-database-to-message-queue-for-apache-kafka)
2. [Using GCP services](https://cloud.google.com/datastream/docs/implementing-datastream-dataflow-analytics)

Change data capture (CDC) is a term used to classify this pattern of reacting to data changes and then delivering those changes in real-time to a downstream process.